# How to make a table-like structure with row/colspans using ExtJS Grid 4.1

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I need to implement a logic using ExtJS 4.1 grid which has the feature of colspan and rowspan.

Comment: Your title was not particularly descriptive, so I've modified it - feel free to amend it further, to describe what it is you are wanting to do. Also, if you can show what you have tried, that helps a lot. At present you seem to have set out requirements for your whole project, and people are certainly not going to do it for you. If you can modify your question to contain the smallest problem possible that, once solved, will allow you to do the rest of it, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution One: ExtJS Grid with rowSpan/colSpan**

If you use a normal ExtJS grid, with one row per parameter value, you can (ab)use the renderer somehow:

```
renderer:function(value, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
    var columnManager = view.ownerCt.getColumnManager(),
        previousRecord = store.getAt(rowIndex-1),
        nextRecord = store.getAt(rowIndex+1),
        column = columnManager.getHeaderAtIndex(colIndex),
        previousColumn = columnManager.getHeaderAtIndex(colIndex-1),
        nextColumn = columnManager.getHeaderAtIndex(colIndex+1),
        cellAbove = view.getCell(previousRecord,column),
        cellBelow = view.getCell(nextRecord,column),
        cellLeft = view.getCell(record, previousColumn),
        cellRight = view.getCell(record, nextColumn);
    ...
    if(someCondition) {
        meta.tdAttr='rowSpan=4';
    } else if (someOtherCondition /* any of the previous three records has someCondition */) {
        meta.tdStyle='display:none';
    }
    return value; // Don't forget this, or else your cell is empty!
}`
```

In a similar fashion, I have once implemented a renderer that merged adjacent cells with same content, because I had to replace an [`MSFlexGrid` with `MergeCells=flexMergeFree`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261240(v=vs.60).aspx).

Four drawbacks I know:

- you have to always get the correct amount of display:none for your colSpan and rowSpan.
- you can't use it easily with special columns (numbercolumns, datecolumns, checkcolumns), because you override their normal renderer.
- your data has to be in a "record with primitive values" form, so when you load the store you would have to walk through the tree and generate the records.
- will no longer work in ExtJS6; not sure about ExtJS 5.

**Solution two: Nested grids**

You can easily [render a grid into a grid's RowExpander plugin](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?151442-Nested-EXTJS-4-Grids&p=668193&viewfull=1#post668193).

```
plugins: [{
    ptype: "rowexpander",
    rowBodyTpl: ['<div id="SessionInstructionGridRow-{ClientSessionId}" ></div>']
    listeners:{
        expandbody:function() {
            var targetId = 'SessionInstructionGridRow-' + record.get('ClientSessionId');
            if (Ext.getCmp(targetId + "_grid") == null) {
                var sessionInstructionGrid = Ext.create('TS.view.client.SessionInstruction', {
                    renderTo: targetId,
                    id: targetId + "_grid"
                });
                rowNode.grid = sessionInstructionGrid;
                sessionInstructionGrid.getEl().swallowEvent(['mouseover', 'mousedown', 'click', 'dblclick', 'onRowFocus']);
                sessionInstructionGrid.fireEvent("bind", sessionInstructionGrid, { ClientSessionId: record.get('ClientSessionId') });
            }
        }
    }
}],
```

The main drawback being that it does look like a grid inside a grid, not like a single grid with rowSpan and colSpan; so it is nowhere near your screenshot. But this is how I implemented display of content of fields containing arrays just today. You could as well render a `propertygrid` into the rowExpander, if you want to show structured data (objects).

Comment: I also need the logic/solution for the given problem